# MongoDB Logging Suspicious Traffic

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'd like to keep a collection of suspicious traffic that resembles the following schema:

```
"_id": ObjectId(###),
"count": NumberInt(6),
"ip": NumberInt(2147483647),
"requests": {
[ "uri": "/path/to/something/",
  "last": NumberInt(1419023477)
  "count": NumberInt(2) ],
[ "uri": "/path/to/something/else/",
  "last": NumberInt(1419023478)
  "count": NumberInt(4) ]
}
```

Can somebody help me with a single upsert that will:

- add the request URI to the embedded document array
- increment the number of requests for that URI
- set the last request date for that URI
- and finally increment overall request count for that IP

Somebody asked me to post what I've got so far:

```
$db->coll->update(array('ip' => $ip),
                array('$addToSet' => array('req' => array('$set' => array('last'  => $timestamp),
                                                          '$inc' => array('count' => 1)))),
                array('upsert' => true)
                );
```

As you can see, it's not yet searching for the embedded doc with the matching uri ($uri)

Comment: You write the code, we help fix it. not the other way around.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the implementation you've tried.

Comment: Your document structure is not valid. Is `requests` meant to be an array of objects?

Comment: I don't have priv yet to comment on your answer, wdberkeley.
There are a fixed number of URIs (24 total), so i wasn't concerned about the array growing out of bounds. But that's a good thing to consider, as you say, if the list increases.

The IP was just converted to an integer (just because i'm happier with integers): http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your document structure. Naively, one IP will make requests to an ever-growing collection of URIs. Having arrays that grow without bound is not a good idea in MongoDB, and you will find it slow and cumbersome to deal with them. I'd suggest basing each document on a request, instead of on an IP, so the documents look like:

```
{
    "ip" : "192.168.1.1",
    "uri" : "/food/cookies/chocolatechip",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-12-22T18:44:26.860Z")
}
```

I put in `last` in as a datetime, which is almost always what you should prefer for datetimes in MongoDB. I renamed it timestamp since it no longer makes sense to call it `last`. Also, why are you storing `ip` as a number? I'm not an expert on the rules for IP addresses, but I think that is dangerous as 192.168.1.1 is not the same IP address as 19.216.81.1 but both give the same number when you drop the .'s.

Now, you accomplish all of your objectives for a single upsert with one insert of a new document. You can use `.count()` to find counts and `.sort()` to find the most recent requests, and can index the necessary queries so these operations are fast.